# Can vue define the data via methods?

Tags: vue.js

Can vue define the data via methods?

[image]

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      navData: [ /* ... */ ],
      defaultData: this.deepClone(this.navData)
    };
  },
```

`deepClone` is a function I define, but this method can not be transmitted to `defaultData` may be about the life cycle? Can you explain it to me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it like that because the object you are returning (the object `navData` belongs to) is not created yet, so `this.navData` is not available.

**Solution:** create the object first, with `navData`, then add `defaultData`:

```
export default {
  data() {
    let data = {
      navData: [ /* ... */ ],
    };
    data.defaultData = this.deepClone(data.navData);
    return data;
  },
```

Another  **alternative** solution, arguably more idiomatic, is to initialize `defaultData` later:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      navData: [ /* ... */ ],
      defaultData: null;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.defaultData = this.deepClone(this.navData);
  },
```